# jQuery each iteration: every gallery element should have title!

Tags: jquery, each

simple and annoying question for you, but i need the answer rather quick and i couldn't find a solution.

```
$('.gallery-item .gallery-icon a').each(function(){
        $('.gallery-caption').prepend("<span class='imgtitle'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</span>")
    });
```

every gallery-item has a gallery-caption underneath it. i'm iterating through every gallery-icon and find the title of the link. i want to prepend the title to every gallery-item-caption.

Right now, every image-caption get ALL image-titles prepended. I just want to prepend the title of the current image.

?

Comment: Please use `this.title` to get the title, instead of creating a new jQuery object with `$(this).attr('title')`. It's also more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the titles prepended on all the captions because of this:

```
$('.gallery-caption').prepend(...
```

This is actually telling jQuery "prepend the following to all elements of class gallery-caption"

EDIT: Assuming that the link is a sibling of the caption, something like this should work:

```
$(this).parent().children('.gallery-caption').prepend(...
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you're prepending all elements that match .gallery-caption condition. You need to specify what element to prepend - like if you need to prepend parent - use .parent()

```
$('.gallery-item .gallery-icon a').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().prepend("<span class='imgtitle'>"+$(this).attr("title")+"</span>")
    });
```

or other traversing methods.